# Visual Studio 2012 / Resharper Unit Tests don't run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, resharper, vs-unit-testing-framework

I used to be able to run unit tests in VS 2012.  Now, all of a sudden, whether I try to "Run" or "Debug" any unit tests, the Unit Test Sessions window puts the test into "Pending" status, but never actually executes it.

I've tried restarting my dev environment, even rebooting the computer.  No change.

So where is the secret setting that says "Make unit tests freeze at 'Pending'"?

Comment: Off topic, but definitely had a giggle at "all of a sardine".

Comment: You seem to be using ReSharper or something, "Unit test sessions"

Comment: @JohnSaunders - yep, resharper.  You deprived other users of the same giggle as Chris Dixon with your edit... :-/

Comment: Which unit test framework are you using?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida - Resharper 7.1.  Added tag and edited subject line.

Comment: How long have you waited for the unit test to run? Last time I ran unit tests with Resharper it took about 8 minutes to run for some reason.

Comment: @Shaul Which framework?NUnit? or other?

Comment: @user1378730 - at this writing, the question is 47 minutes old.  I spent about half an hour trying to get the unit tests to run (after rebooting) before turning to the gold folks at SO fo help.  And the unit tests are still "Pending"...

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida - this may seem dumb, but I'm not actually sure.  I never installed NUnit, so I'm assuming it's a native Visual Studio unit testing framework.  How would I tell?

Comment: Its a resharper issue - http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442769. Check if your Resharper and/or VS2012 versions are the ones affected

Comment: In visual studio go Test->Run->All Tests or press CTRL+R, A, looks like resharper doesn't support MS Tests very well.

Comment: @user1378730 - Spot on, please post that Resharper link as the answer so I can award credit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My answer in the comments was correct

Its a resharper issue - [see here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/442769). Check if your Resharper and/or VS2012 versions are the ones affected

Comment: Take note that the posted issue is for version 7.1.2. I'm using 8.2 and suspect that this bug would have been fixed from the 7.1.2.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd add this in case it helps others, I did these steps...

- Closed VS and reopened, **running as Administrator**.
- Cleaned the solution, and rebuilt
- Kicked off the tests, and they started working again

It might have been that I needed to only run as admin, but I thought I'd add all the steps I did.

Comment: Terrific, this did it for me! Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, 12.0.31101.00 Update 4, Resharper 8.2.3000.5176 Full Edition. Stalling of the unit tests with eternal "pending" state happened directly after upgrading to VS Update 4. Performed the steps you described, worked afterwards like a charm. Might be solved in Resharper 9, don't know, since I need plugins available only for up to 8.2 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616649/antlr4-c-sharp-targets-and-output-path-of-generated-files/22429568#22429568).

Answer (score 5):

Goto Resharper -> Options -> General and hit the button "Clear Caches". Restart Visual Studio and unit testing should work again. No idea why this happened to me all of the sudden.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what state your machine is in but what I would do, like debugging the code I would try and narrow down the route of the issue, So for example

1. Check to see if your unit test has an initializer method, if it has then put a break point there and see what happens when you debug your test.
2. Check your settings both bitness and platform ... so 64bit or 86 or AnyCPU and also debug or release settings.
3. Finally try running a fake simple test that you can just write in seconds and see if you can narrow it down that.

Comment: 1. Doesn't hit breakpoint in initializer; 2. Everything set to "Any CPU"; 3. Simple test doesn't run either.

Comment: Uncommented Downvote Ninja struck at you, not sure why.  I gave you +1 back just to balance things... :)

Comment: Thanks, That resharper issue talked above would also be likely. but ill stick to the basics :D